# How to convert a pic binay file into text file and transfer it with python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets

My problem:
I have many clients + one server in LAN. I want to take a screenshot of client's desktop and transfer the pic via python socket  to the server.

I have problem with rebuilding(convert pic.txt to pic.png) the received pic from the client.

Note:
if we can fix the issue on local-machine(works the converting a pic file to a text file and build a pic binary file from a text file,,then: everything is good and done.)

client-script.py:

```
#if the recieved CMD is pic, take screenShot and send to server#
#the part of send the pic's data.#
if str(en_data) == "pic":
      img_real = ImageGrab.grab()
      img_real.save('a_old.png')
      img_converted = Image.open('a_old.png').convert('L')
      img_converted.save('a_new.png','png')
      buffersize = 999000  
      f1 = open("a_new.png", "rb")
      buffer = f1.readlines()
      f1.close()
      txt_buffer = (str(buffer))
      txt_buffer = txt_buffer.split(", ")

      if os.path.isfile("a_ali.txt"):
           os.remove("a_ali.txt")
      else: pass
      for i in txt_buffer:
           f2 = open("a_ali.txt", "a+")
           f2.write(i+'\n')
           f2.close();
      f3 = open("a_ali.txt", "r")
      line = f3.readline()
      while line:
          #print str(line).rstrip("\n")
          en_output = bytearray(line)
          #time.sleep(0.3)
          for i in range(len(en_output)):
             en_output[i] ^=0x41
          s.send(en_output)
          line = f3.readline()
      en_output = "finish"
      for i in range(len(en_output)):
          en_output[i] ^=0x41
      s.send(en_output)
      f3.close()     
      del img_real, img_converted, buffer, txt_buffer
```

Server-Script.py

```
import socket, thread
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.bind(("192.168.1.2", 443))
except:
    print "Connection/Socket Error... (=__+)";
    pass;
s.listen(250)
print "Listening on port 443... "
##(client, (ip, port)) = s.accept()
##print "Received connection from: ", ip

def Clients_Threads (client, ip):
    while True:
        command = raw_input('~CMD(%s):' %ip)
        if command == "exit":
            client.close()
            break;
        elif command == "pic":
            encode = bytearray(command)
            for i in range(len(encode)):
               encode[i] ^=0x41
            client.send(encode) 
            img_real = []
            while True:
                en_data=client.recv(8192)
                decode = bytearray(en_data)
                for i in range(len(decode)):
                    decode[i] ^=0x41
                print decode.rstrip("\n")
                if decode == "finish":
                    print img_real
                    client.close();
                else:
                    img_real.append(decode)
            client.close();
        else:
            encode = bytearray(command)
            for i in range(len(encode)):
               encode[i] ^=0x41
            client.send(encode) 
            en_data=client.recv(8192)
            decode = bytearray(en_data)
            for i in range(len(decode)):
               decode[i] ^=0x41
            print decode
        client.close();
```

LOCAL-MACHINE: Take screenshot and create a pic file, then write pic's binary contents into a text file and build a pic file from a text file.

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
img_real = ImageGrab.grab()
img_real.save('a_old.png')
img_converted = Image.open('a_old.png').convert('L')
img_converted.save('a_new.png','png')

buffersize = 999000  
f1 = open("a_new.png", "rb")
buffer = f1.readlines()
f1.close()
txt_buffer = (str(buffer))
txt_buffer = txt_buffer.split(", ")
if os.path.isfile("a_ali.txt"):
    os.remove("a_ali.txt")
else: pass;
print txt_buffer

for i in txt_buffer:
    f2 = open("a_ali.txt", "a+")
    f2.write(i+'\n')
f2.write('')
f2.close()
img_real = open("hack_ali.txt").readlines()
print img_real
for n,line in enumerate(img_real):
    if line.startswith("line"):
       img_real[n] = "\n"+line.rstrip()
    else:
       img_real[n]=line.rstrip()
final_img_real = ", ".join(img_real)

f3 = open("final_img_real.png", "wb")
f3.writelines(final_img_real)
f3.close()

del img_real, img_converted, buffer, txt_buffer
```

Comment: please highlight where you receives error. and expected response

Comment: Hi dear. the program doesn't have errors.
when new image file is created(build binary pic file from text file), then new pic file doesn't show the pic as original pic file.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using Pyenbeddedimage via img2py:
Generate a library of the images that you wish to send into a .py file

```
from wx.tools.img2py import img2py
from glob import glob
f = open('Image_catalogue.py', 'w')
f.close()
x=0
for f in glob('*.png'):
    output_file = f.replace('-', '').replace('_', '').replace('.png', '')
    if x==0:
        img2py(f, 'Image_catalogue.py', append=False, catalog=True, imgName=output_file, icon=True)
    else:
        img2py(f, 'Image_catalogue.py', append=True, catalog=True, imgName=output_file, icon=True)
    x+=1
```

(Note: the first image added cannot be appended and the library .py file must exist)

Transmit the file over the network and then at the receiving end, take the .py image library file and generate the images from it by `importing` the generated library.

```
import Image_catalogue
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
for i in Image_catalogue.catalog:
    print "Converting image..", i
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(Image_catalogue.catalog[i].GetData()))
    im.save(i+'.png', 'PNG')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it didn't help me.
I'm looking for find a way for sending a binary file(pic) via python socket. :(

Comment: Your question specifically asked "How to convert a pic binay file into text file and transfer it", my solution converts binary "picture", notably .png in this example, into text ready for transmission via sockets and a method to convert that text file back into .png files. I assume then, that you are referring to files with a (dot) .pic file extension. I see no reason why you should not be able to transmit such a file using sockets. Perhaps your problem is being able to display a .pic file at the other end. I had thought that your question was clear, now I have no idea what your problem is.